# Database Design for student management tool

Tags: database-design

At my company we have students that are being trained go through the different groups of the department. For example in the IT department there would be the Linux Administration, Networking and User Support groups.

A while back I created a tool to schedule the stays in the various groups. Now I was asked to extend it to be used for all departments on campus.

The intended usage looks like this:

- an entry in 'users' for each person to use the tool
- the roles admin, student and user can be assigned to users
- an entry in 'persons' for every student, referencing a 'user'
- groups stays, time in school and days of leave defined in 'absences'
- all of the above (except for roles) should be confined to a department, which will be determined by the logged-in users department

My question regards the usage of 'departments'. The way I have it feels like bad practice. What would be a better way of doing this.

My ERD:[image: student management erd]

Comment: Side note: Please call columns properly... Why not DepartmentId instead of 'did'? Sure it makes sense to you *now* because you just created it, but when someone else has to look at the schema its unnecessary mental load

Comment: On your actual question: Are you sure that groups/students will never be in more than one department? That seems strange...

Comment: @Milney Yes, but maybe the word student isn't ideal, they actually are apprentices and are only being trained in that one department.

Comment: What about the actual users? When someone needs to manage multiple departments? Thinks like this tend to 'never happen'.... until they do

Comment: @Milney The idea is that a department consists of multiple groups, each with a 'group leader'. These groups are exclusive to their department. Apprentices will then go through them during their training. Admins can add 'users' to departments but only modify 'persons' in their own department.

Comment: I mean... you don't need to justify it to me... You asked if it was 'best practice' and I answered no, because you are making some assumptions that don't sound like they will **always** hold. If your assumptions are correct and never change then your design is fine, however in my experience assumptions like that will always be broken at some point down the line and you'll have to add support for one admin to manage multiple departments or something similar

Comment: For instance, you say "Admins can **add** 'users' to departments". In your current design, this statement is false - Admins can actually only **assign** a user to a single department...

Comment: @Milney Oh I was just clarifying that in case I worded it poorly before. I do appreciate your feedback.